# jQuery animate squishes content?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, jquery-animate

Simple question with a lot of nuance, since I am picking up jQuery as I go...

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="flip_body">
                <div id="top_body">
                        <div id="top_body_left">
                        <p id="text">This will be a really long string to test if things get squished</p>
                        <div id="left_test" class="test">
                        </div>
                        <div id="right_test" class="test">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="top_body_right">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bottom_body">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="flip">
                <p>Flip</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container
{
    width:1000px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:red;
}
#header
{
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background-color:orange;
}
#body
{
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#top_body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;

}
#bottom_body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:pink;
    display:none;

}
#flip_body
{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#flip
{
    width:10%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}
#top_body_left
{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:teal;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
}
#top_body_right
{   
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
    top:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}
#text
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#left_test
{
    background-color:orange;

}
#right_test
{
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
}
.test
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#footer
{
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#flip").data("open", false);

    $("#flip").click(function() {
        // slide to the right
        if ($(this).data("open") == false) {            
            $("#top_body_left").animate({width:'toggle'},500);
            $("#top_body_right").animate({width: '+=100', duration:500});

            $(this).data("open", true);
        }
        // slide to the left
        else {
                $("#top_body_left").animate({width:'toggle'},500);
            $("#top_body_right").animate({width:'-=100'},500);

            $(this).data("open", false);
        }
    });

});
```

How do I prevent the `#top_body_left` `div` from changing the arrangement of the children (`#left_test` and `#right_test`)? Is there a way to toggle without the floats moving or any content being wrapped? I read about using css clip, but I'm not sure that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fiddle to look at. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/4PG7w/

Floated left elements will fill their container left to right. If they do not fit then they will wrap to a new line. You could instead place them in a container with `overflow: hidden`. This prevents them from wrapping.

Example Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/4PG7w/1/

Comment: Sergi had the correct answer first and is new. So give him the checkmark if you like this solution. He earned those points!

Comment: Wow, so the only change to make this work is adding an extra div as the parent of the elements I don't want squished. Ie: you added: <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 250px;"> But before I added that I tried adding a different div with an ID and then adding overflow:hidden to the css for that ID. Does CSS not interact with jquery that way I want it to? Or should all div's in this kind of situation have inline styles? Doesn't that break the idea of separating style and behavior?

Comment: Ok I just tried a few things, I fixed my CSS problem, but I found another. Does animate() ignore overflow:hidden? When I get rid of the extra <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 250px;"> and put overflow:hidden into <div id="top_body_left"> my code does not work, but when I restore <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 250px;"> everything works fine. What gives?

Comment: @Steve - you don't need inline styles. If your CSS is not working then something is wrong with it. jQuery should always obey your style rules unless it explicitly is meant to override them. The reason why placing the style properties in `top_body_left` fails is because your `left_test` and `right_test` are floated. Remember that this pulls them out of the typical layout flow. By explicitly placing them in a nonfloated container you prevent them from wrapping. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/4PG7w/2/.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with overflow:hidden. When I change #mrtsherman to have either width:100% of delete the width altogether, the animate fails. When I restore width:250px, the animate succeeds... so this animate will not work on a div has a width that is not in the form of a px?

Comment: I think you need to read up on how floats work. Floats fill their container. If there is not room they wrap to the next line. If their container is set to 100% and you shrink it... then they aren't going to fit are they?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to encapsulate the contents in another container and add overflow:hidden to the inner container (that's for every block that you want to squish), then squish the outer one.

Comment: Yea I saw a fix from mrtsherman, but it seems like I cannot use CSS when I want to add this overflow:hidden parent. I have to use an inline style? Why is that.